# Search between different TFS / projects - visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, search, tfs

Got 5 different TFS, is there a way to search in all TFS's? Visual studio plugin?

Right now I've downloaded all the source code to my local machine and turned on indexing on serveral filetypes (properties and inside files)..

If anyone has the same problem, how do you solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Why do you have 5 instance of TFS? Consolidate them.

Comment: I'm working between different projects, and they all got different tfs's, 2010, 2012, 2015 , online and so on..

Answer (score 1):

Never heard this kind of tools or plugin.

In a sense, there are different Application Lifecycle Management system. They have different servers, SQL servers, users, permission settings and so on. Searching between them, how could this be possible to achieve. Unless, you choose to migrate different projects to one instance of TFS.

---

**OpsHub Integration Manager** supports bi-directional synchronization between a wide variety of systems including Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio Online. It can be used for bi-directional sync between TFS and VSO. For more information please reach out to OpsHub at http://www.opshub.com/main/index.php/company/contactus

Comment: Is there a good way go "sync" between different tfs and my personal online tfs :) ? Or do I manually have to download it from the tfs's and upload it on the online?

Comment: No, you don't need to. OpsHub Integration Manager supports bi-directional synchronization between a wide variety of systems including Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio Online. It can be used for bi-directional sync between TFS and VSO. For more information please reach out to OpsHub at http://www.opshub.com/main/index.php/company/contactus  However, some functions are not free :)